# MS Access 2007/2003 - Referencing a control on a sub form, from the parent form

Tags: ms-access, vba

So if I want to reference a control (like a text box) on a sub form, from the CBF of the parent form, how should I do this?

```
me.SubForm.SubControl
```

Gives me an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Me.SubformControlName.Form.SomeControl
```

Be sure to use the name of the subform control, not the form contained - they are often the same, but not always.

More info: http://www.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Comment: For those who use ! instead of . that would be Me!SubformControlName.Form!SomeControl.